# FATAL ERROR : Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

Tags: php, slim

I try some codes to build a RESTful API Web Service using PHP and slim framework.
(I'm using Advanced Rest Client for testing this code)

This is my codes.

`private function isUserExists($email) {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT id from users WHERE email = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $num_rows = $stmt->num_rows;
        $stmt->close();
        return $num_rows > 0;
    }`

and then I got this error.

> Fatal Error : Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object on Line 113

Line 113 is : `$stmt->bind_param("s", $email);`

I've been looking for a solution of this problem since 2 weeks ago.

Thanks before guys :))

Comment: I already use the correct table sir

Comment: is `$this->conn` an instance of `mysqli`?

Comment: include your connection in your post

Comment: The problem comes from the `prepare()` call. When `prepare()` encounters an error it [returns `false`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php#refsect1-mysqli.prepare-returnvalues). This results in `$stmt` not being an object, which is the reason you are receiving this error. You should check the `$stmt` variable before using it, and if there is an error echo out `$this->conn->error`, in order to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: @Ghost : it's just a var

Comment: @JohnRobertson : Already Sir

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen: if you do not mind to fix my error codes because it's my first time learning bout web service

Comment: `$this->conn->prepare` this part is the problem you should check your connection

Comment: Thanks guys, the problem already solved !! :D
Cheers !

Comment: @RendySetyaPratama Sorry, I do not work pro bono.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in `$this->conn->prepare`, which does not return an object, as you would expect.

For mysqli, [prepare()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) returns FALSE on error. You can check the error message using [$this->conn->error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php).

This code should print your error in case of failure:

```
private function isUserExists($email) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT id from users WHERE email = ?");
    if ($stmt === FALSE){
        die($this->conn->error);
    } else  {
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $num_rows = $stmt->num_rows;
        $stmt->close();
        return $num_rows > 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much ! The problem already solved by now :D cheers !

Comment: If your problem was solved using this answer, please mark it as accepted. Otherwise, please post your solution for other users to find.